# How to open files in default app on Xamarin Form iOS

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am trying to open document using default app in Xamarin Forms for editing. I tried the below approach but it is opening the file in read only mode. I want to open in read write mode so that I can edit the document. How can I do this in xamarin form iOS ?

await Launcher.OpenAsync(new OpenFileRequest { File = new ReadOnlyFile(uri) });

Comment: Where is the file stored?

Comment: I have saved the doc under      Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal

Comment: @Jason I have saved the doc under Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal

Answer (score 0):

You could try [File.OpenRead](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.openread?view=net-7.0) and [File.OpenWrite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.openwrite?view=net-7.0) method to read or write a file.

```
var path = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal),"myfile");
using (FileStream fs = File.OpenWrite(path))
{
     Byte[] info = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes("This is to test the OpenWrite method.");
    // Add some information to the file.
    fs.Write(info, 0, info.Length);
 }
```

Hope it works for you.